# Symbolic link to change directory only works from home dir

Tags: bash, symlink, cd-command

Using [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27427/52183) answer, I have created a symbolic link in my `.bashrc` file to make changing to a frequently used directory easier.

E.g.

```
ln -s ~/a/b/c/d/development dev
```

I can change directory from my `home` dir to the `development` dir by entering `cd dev`. I can also enter `ls dev` from my `home` dir and that works too.

However, these commands *only* work in my `home` dir. If I enter them from anywhere else I get an error telling me `No such file or directory`.

If I enter `cd ~/dev` or `ls ~/dev` it works.

Can someone explain why that is and how I can fix it so I don't have to include `~/` in the path when I'm not in my home dir.

Comment: you don't want to put `ln` into a start up script, as the result is persistent.

Comment: symlinks work that way: they are a like from a particular place, to another place. see this question for the answers you seek  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31161/quick-directory-navigation-in-the-bash-shell/31221

Comment: Yes, this just runs the same command every time you start a shell and that just results in an error message. You just need to run that *once* and the link is created for ever.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise the links persisted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you’re using Bash as your shell, you can use the `CDPATH` shell
variable. The [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) describes it as

> a search path: each directory name in CDPATH is searched for directory, with
>   alternative directory names in CDPATH separated by a colon (‘:’)

You could add the following line to your `.bashrc`:

```
CDPATH=".:$HOME"
```

If you later type `cd dev`, the current working directory would be searched for a sub-directory named `dev`:

- If such a directory exists, it changes into that directory (as the `cd` builtin command usually works).
- If not, it would then search your home directory (`~`), find the symbolic link (realise that it’s a link to a directory) and change to the target directory (pointed to by `~/dev`).

If you wanted to give preference to the directories within your home directory, you could list `$HOME` first in your `CDPATH` (`"$HOME:."`) but I would strongly advise against that as it breaks the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment): the resulting behaviour differs too greatly from the standard.

Answer (score 9):

You can't. How could you? The `ln` command creates a file that is a link to another file (or directory, or whatever). You can then use the link as though it were the original. But this is still just a file. It has a specific path, it's not just magically floating around and accessible from anywhere in the filesystem. Just like with any other file, you can't simply call it by name, you need to use its path.

Just like if you create a regular file:

```
$ cd ~/foo
$ touch file
$ cd ~/
$ ls file
ls: cannot access 'file': No such file or directory
$ ls ~/foo/file
file
```

A link is no different. You can't just cd `cd dev` from a random directory and expect it to work, just like you can't do `cat file` in a random directory and expect the system to magically know what file you want.

You can get the behavior you're looking for by using a script or a function, but not a link. For example, add these lines to your shell's initialization file (`~/.bashrc` for bash):

```
dev(){
    cd "$HOME"/dev
}
```

Or just:

```
alias dev='cd ~/dev'
```

Now, running `dev` will take you to `~/dev`. Alternatively, define a variable in your `~/bashrc` or `~/.profile`:

```
dev="$HOME/dev"
```

You can now run `cd $dev` and be taken to `~/dev`. This is possible in many ways, but links are not relevant.