# Bash script to replace two steps: cd ./some_dir, ls -al?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ls, cd-command

I'd like to write a bash scipt that would change to target directory and list the contents of new directory, all in one step. It would replace the two commands I constantly use consecutively:

- cd ./some_directory
- ls -al

After executing the script, my current directory would change, and ls -al would show the dir list.

```
cdl ./some_directory
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Not with a script, because script runs in a subshell, and its changes in the current directory aren't reflected in the parent process. You can declare a function, though.

Comment: So what's wrong with `ls -al ./some_directory`?

Comment: I want to `cd` into directory, and then `ls -al`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t do this with a shell script, because scripts run in new shells and exiting the script exits the shell and “forgets” the directory change. See [Script to change current directory (cd, pwd)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27139/86440) for example (there are probably more detailed answers on the site somewhere).

You need to use a function instead:

```
cd1() {
    cd "$@"
    ls -al
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Where do I put function to? `.bash_profile`?

Comment: `.bashrc` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Another option (in your .bashrc):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='if [[ "$PWD" != "$_promptPWD" ]]; then ls -al; _promptPWD=$PWD; fi'
_promptPWD=$PWD
```

That hooks into bash's PROMPT_COMMAND functionality to have it run the `ls` for you, if you've changed directories. The downsides are:

- would need to be patched into any existing PROMPT_COMMAND, if any
- clutters the environment with another variable (`_promptPWD`)

The up-side is that you can continue to type `cd` as normal, and not need to type something different to get the `ls` behavior.