# Run cd with path variable in bash script not working

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable-substitution

When i run the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DRUPAL_ROOT=$(drush status root --format=list)
if [ -z $DRUPAL_ROOT ]
then
  echo -e "Not exists Drupal core"
else
  echo $DRUPAL_ROOT
  cd $DRUPAL_ROOT
fi
```

Output:

```
# /right/drupal/root
```

But no change to path

If i run commands in terminal:

```
# DRUPAL_ROOT=$(drush status root --format=list)
# cd $DRUPAL_ROOT
```

Change OK

Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: More directly: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27139/117549

Comment: The script will `cd` into the directory, and then terminate, leaving you in the shell (and working directory) in which you invoked the script, not the script's final working dorectory.  This can be shown by adding a `pwd` line after the `cd` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, scripts are executed in subshells, so it is for that reason why the directory does not change. You can source the script with `.` or `source`, or create a function for this:

```
drup_cd() {
   DRUPAL_ROOT=$(drush status root --format=list)
   if [[ ! $DRUPAL_ROOT ]]; then
     echo -e "Not exists Drupal core"
   else
     echo "$DRUPAL_ROOT"
     cd "$DRUPAL_ROOT"
   fi
}
```

You can add it to your `.bashrc`, for example. Also note that using unquoted variables inside `[ ]` is prone to errors.