# $ find -exec cd => gives error: => find: ‘cd’: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, find, cd-command

When I run this command it works:

```
$ find . -inum 888696 -exec ls '{}' \;
Conversation.pst  Outlook Data File  Outlook Data File.sbd  Trash      Unsent Messages
Inbox.pst     Outlook Data File.msf  Sent.pst       Trash.msf  Unsent Messages.msf
```

---

However, When replacing `ls` with `cd` it does **not** work:

```
$ find . -inum 888696 -exec cd '{}' \;
find: ‘cd’: No such file or directory
```

---

I know `cd` is a `bash` built-in, so I tried this which does **not** work either:

```
$ find . -inum 888696 -exec builtin cd '{}' \;
find: ‘builtin’: No such file or directory
```

---

How can I use `cd` along with `find -exec` command?

---

### UPDATE

The reason I'm trying to use `cd` with `find -exec` is that the directory name is a strange one which shows up on my terminal as something like `????`.

Comment: BTW, you can `LC_ALL=C printf '%q\n' *` to print ASCII names for all files in your current directory, one to a line (changing newlines to `$'\n'` or similar).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `-exec` option to `find` executes an external utility, possibly with some command line option and other arguments.

Your Unix does not provide `cd` as an external utility, only as a shell built-in, so `find` fails to execute it.  At least macOS and Solaris *do* provide `cd` as an external utility.

There would be little or no use for executing `cd` in this way, except as a way of testing whether the pathname found by `find` is a directory into which you would be able to `cd`.  The working directory in your interactive shell (or whatever is calling `find`) would not change anyway.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)
- [Script to change current directory (cd, pwd)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27139)
- [What is the point of the `cd` external command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/)

---

If you're having issues with a directory's name being strange or extremely difficult to type, and you want to change into that directory, then consider creating a symbolic link to the directory and then `cd` into it using that link instead:

```
find . -inum 888696 -exec ln -s {} thedir ';'
```

This would create a symbolic link named `thedir` that would  point to the problematic directory.  You may then change working directory with

```
cd thedir
```

(if the link exists in the current directory).  This avoids modifying the directory in any way.  Another idea would be to rename the directory in a similar way with `find`, but that would not be advisable if another program expects the directory to have that particular name.

Comment: The reason I intent to use `cd` with `find -exec` is that the directory names are in some strange characters which don't show up correctly on my terminal.

Comment: @user3405291 It is not clear from the question what you expect to happen when you run the command. Do you expect to change directory in the interactive shell?

Comment: Yes, I just want to `cd` into a directory which has a **bad** name, and I cannot `cd` into it in a normal way.

Comment: @user3405291 See update.

Comment: What's funny is that `/bin/cd` is a result of POSIX (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_06) where the normal builtins have to be accessible to exec().  Of course, `/bin/cd` likely doesn't do what people want :-)

Comment: @StephenHarris The Solaris `cd` manual mentions that about the _only_ use for the external `cd` utility is to test whether changing working directory would be allowed or not.

Comment: Regarding the bad characters, you can always use wildchards.  You can use "ls -b" to find out the "bad" characters, and replace them by dots for your cd command, eg.  "cd bd.....dir".

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Well, that works if you can type _any_ of the name's characters.  I'm imagining the situation where you actually _can't_. My solution also results in a handy symbolic link that would be easy to use many times around, and it leaves the original directory unmodified (in case something depend upon its name).

Comment: The symbolic link solution is simple and easy to remember. Thanks.

Comment: @user3405291 can you give us an example of such a name?  The "ls -b" should allow you to cut and paste it in your question.  I'm just asking to see if the problem is not with your terminal settings iso with the directory.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, just mind that `ls -b` escapes "nongraphic" characters, and that concept might still include some pretty weird things in these times and ages... e.g. Hebrew or emojis may be somewhat difficult to enter on an English keyboard, even though they're still quite much "graphical"

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Thanks. I was not aware of `ls -b`, however looks like the directory name is more weird in my case.

Comment: See also [What is the point of the \`cd\` external command?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/50058)

Comment: @user3405291 if it's that weird, you'd better not show it to us.  You can always "srm" it.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille What is `srm`? Well, I know I can google it ... :)

Answer (score 7):

`find` runs the `-exec` command itself, it doesn't involve a shell. Even if it did, the change of directory would only persist until that shell exited, immediately after the `cd`.

You'll need to get the filename out to the current shell to `cd` into it. Depending on how bad your filenames are, you could use command substitution:

```
cd "$(find . -inum 888696)"
```

That won't work if the filename ends in a newline, as command substitution eats trailing newlines. In that case you'd need to protect the newline and get rid of the one `find` adds when printing:

```
dir=$(find . -inum 888696; echo x)
cd "${dir%?x}"
```

Or, with GNU `find`, have it not print the trailing newline (but still protect any in the filename):

```
dir=$(find . -inum 888696 -printf "%px" -quit)
cd "${dir%x}"
```

Also using the `-quit` predicate (also a GNU extension), to stop looking after the first match as an optimisation.

Alternatively, you could start a new shell from within `find`, but it's a bit ugly:

```
find . -inum 888696 -exec bash -c 'cd "$1" && exec bash' sh {} \;
```

Comment: Tried your trick with the "echo x", on directories ending with newline, carriage return and both, without success.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, oh, sorry, I forgot the newline `find` itself adds when printing. Edited.

Comment: If you replace the printf by a print0, you can do ' cd "$dir" '.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, perhaps. But Bash ignores any nul bytes in input from a command substitution, and removes the trailing newline only after that. So `dir=$(find -print0)` will still trash the trailing newline of the filename...

Answer (score 5):

Not with exec, but this may be good enough for you:

```
cd "$(find . -inum 888696 -type d)"
```

The "-type d", just to be sure.  Of what, I don't really know.

Comment: This fails if the directory's name ends with a newline.

Comment: Sure, but directories rarely do.  If I try to create one on a linux ext4, I get "protocol error".  Don't you think this is a waste of time?

Comment: Well, names rarely have unprintable characters, but this one obviously do.

Comment: What filesystems allow newlines in directory names?

Comment: All Unix filesystems should allow newlines in directory names, just like in the name of any file.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, how did you test that? `mkdir $'foo\n'` works perfectly here; I've yet to see a native UNIX filesystem where it *wasn't* supported.

Comment: I'll crawl back under my stone, I was in a Windoze shared folder when I tried the mkdir.  Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea maxima culpa.

Answer (score 5):

Use a NUL-delimited stream to read output from `find` that works in **all** cases -- including names that end in newlines. Also, you can use `printf '%q'` to generate a readable representation of a filename.

```
inum=888696
if IFS= read -r -d '' filename < <(find . -inum "$inum" -print0); then
  LC_ALL=C printf 'Located filename: %q\n' "$filename" >&2
  cd -- "$filename"
else
  echo "No file located for inode $inum" >&2
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

If you get this message, then **your OS platform is buggy.** The POSIX standard requires that a command named `cd` must be available in the file system so it may be called via `exec()`.

Now the bad news for you:

Even if your OS platform was not buggy, you just did not see a warning, but you did not get your expected results, since it does not help you if a separate program changes its current working directory and immediately dies after that.

If you like to have an effective `cd` in a command executed by `find`, you may do something like:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'cd "$1"; some other command' dummy {} \;
```

Comment: That is only a bug if that platform claims POSIX conformance. [Having a standalone cd utility is not very useful, so it makes sense to ignore that requirement otherwise](/q/50058) without it affecting the usability of the platform. Note that leaving a parameter expansion unquoted has a very special meaning in `sh`, not something you'd want to do. It's better to avoid _dummy_ values for that inline script's `$0` as that's used in error messages for instance (like when that `cd` would fail).

Comment: Did you mean `cd "$1"`?  If the name is hard to type, it may well also contain shell metacharacters...

Comment: correct this was a typo