# How to find a file and make that the current working directory (cd)

Tags: find, cd-command

I am trying to make an executable script on Mac where it searches for a file and makes that the current directory (`cd`) and then runs some more commands. I started with

```
find . -type d  -name "MCsniperPY-master" -exec cd {}
```

And it says I need a + or a ;

- I add a `+` and the cmd does nothing,
- I add a `;` and it says I need a `+` or `;`

I am pretty new to Unix coding, so if there is a better way to do this let me know.

Comment: Related (only difference is that `cd` is not an external command in this other question): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447965/find-exec-cd-gives-error-find-cd-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `cd` as argument of find's `-exec` will result in change directory inside `find` command, when `find` command exit, you are still in starting directory.

I would use

```
cd "$(find . -type d  -name "MCsniperPY-master" -print | head -1)"
```

where

- `find . -type d  -name "MCsniperPY-master" -print`  search for all directories named "MCsniperPY-master" and print then
- `head -1` will retain the first one (you may omit if you are sure there is only one)
- `cd "$( ... )"` will `cd` to that directory (or bring you back to `$HOME` dir if nothing is found)

---

You may wish to use `$CDPATH` that list a set of directory to search for when using `cd`

Comment: No,it does not change the directory in the `find` command, but only in the `cd` command. BTW: this `find` command would only work on a POSIX compliant platform, where `cd` exists as binary command and not e.g. on Linux where such a command is missing.

Comment: @schily: do you mean *external command* in contrary to a *shell built-in*?

Comment: last time I use mac, I recall shell was `zsh`, so this might work if zsh is POSIX. I found this question : https://serverfault.com/questions/93388/is-there-any-reason-to-use-bash-over-zsh

Comment: POSIX requires `cd` to exist as external command as well. Since `find` does not use the shell to call commands, this is not related to shells. BTW: @Archemar I do not see any relation to this question and `zsh` is definitely not POSIX compliant.

Comment: You are a legend ty <3