# Add variable to cd directory path

Tags: bash, shell-script, cd-command

I know these questions might have been asked somewhere but their solutions don't really work. I need help.

I want to add a variable to a directory name then change directory to it. The approach below did not work for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
targetVmwareVersion="15.5.6"
cd vmware-host-modules-workstation-$targetVmwareVersion
```

If I replace `cd` with `ls`, it lists contents of the folder on the terminal but the `cd` does not work.

I want the `targetVmwareVersion` to be concatenated after the name `vmware-host-modules-workstation-` then change directory.

I have tried the approach below but it didn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
targetVmwareVersion="15.5.6"
path="vmware-host-modules-workstation-$targetVmwareVersion"
cd $path
```

The `cd` part does not work. The directory does not change.

`. ./script` does not work for me. The snippet above is part of my large script which depends on that snippet to proceed.

Comment: `. scriptname` is also an option.

Comment: My problem is the directory does not change after concatenation

Comment: Is that `vmware-host-modules-workstation...` directory in your current directory when you run `. ./script`? Do any errors get reported?

Comment: I dont get any errors

Comment: How is the code snippet invoked from the code that needs it to proceed? If it is invoked as a separate script, then I'm not surprised that it does not work as you can't change the current directory for a parent process from a child process. See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27139/script-to-change-current-directory-cd-pwd

Comment: This is the logic. I needed to concatenate the target version which is user input, to the name vmware-host-modules-workstation-  so it would be something like vmware-host-modules-workstation- 15.5.6. I then wanted to change the directory to this folder now called vmware-host-modules-workstation- 15.5.6 and work on the files inside it. I'm doing all this in a single script not different.

Comment: _"these questions might have been asked somewhere but their solutions don't really work." -- umm, so what solutions exactly didn't work? If you would tell that, it might make it easier to figure out where the problem is here.

Comment: If I copy/paste that script into a directory that has `vmware-host-modules-workstation-15.5.6` as a subdirectory and then execute `. ./script`, my current directory is changed to `vmware-host-modules-workstation-15.5.6`.  I would caution you to avoid a variable named "path" (because it's close to "PATH") but your environment has something else that's interfering.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, or you ever use zsh: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-path

Comment: @ilkkachu indeed; I did a quick test with zsh, but since `cd` is built-in, it succeeded anyway, so I'm stumped.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, the problem isn't that, the problem is what it does to your `PATH` after that.

Comment: @David I'm really confused why the `cd` command would silently fail. Can you please expand on "does not work" -- in your question? No errors at all? Perhaps you can wrap your tests (before and after) with `pwd`.

Comment: The cd command did not work after concatenating that version to the name. I used ls in place of `cd` just to check if the folder exists or is been seeing and the ls command listed the contents of that folder. My problem was, I wanted that `cd` command to switch the directory on terminal and do something within that folder. The `cd` command did not change directory. I don't know if it opened a sub-shell. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get no error, your path is changing, well, yours not, the shell's current path. I'll explain myself:

When you cd into another dir within a script, the script changes to that dir you're telling him to, but once the script finishes, you are in the same path because your prompt hasn't moved along the script.

They say one image is worth more than one thousand words, so here goes the demonstration:

[image: Demo image of cd changing path within script]

Comment: How can I make my script remain in that new directory. In my end the cd does not change directory and it gives no errors

Comment: @DavidKariuki A child process (the script) can not change the working directory, or _anything_ in the environment, of its parent process (the interactive shell). See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27139/script-to-change-current-directory-cd-pwd

Comment: I think that's not possible, since the script is a child process of the parent process which is the shell it is invoked from,  the only way I can think of is invoking the script as a separate process, then cd into the directory and invoking another shell from inside the script, but that's not a proper way to do it. What do you actually wish to accomplish with this? What's your aim?

Comment: I wanted to get into that directory, then extract some tar files from within the folder.

Comment: I chose another work around. To copy contents of the folder to my current working directory then extract the tars then proceed. Thank you for the elaboration. I did not know a sub shell is opened when I run a script.

Comment: Is there any other work around. Maybe changing the directory in the subshell then making the parent shell recognise the change?

Comment: No, there is no way of having a subprocess change the parent's working directory since if this was posible it could lead to security breaches.

Comment: Ok, thanks alot.